# Qt Linguist and pylupdate4: which base for relative paths in .ts files?

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

### Edit March 3rd 2015

This issue should be fixed in next PyQt versions for PyQt4 and PyQt5:

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2015-April/035772.html

### Question

`pylupdate4` takes a project file (`.pro`) in which the file paths are relative to the `.pro` file itself.

When parsing the code, `pylupdate4` copies the paths to the `.ts` file.

When Qt Linguist reads the `.ts` file, it considers the paths relative to the `.ts` file, not the `.pro` file. Therefore, it doesn't find the source files and can't display the code while translating.

How can I get Qt Linguist to display the source code ?

I could put the `.pro` file in the `ts/` directory with the `.ts` files, but this looks like a sorry workaround. Is this how it is meant to be ?

Considering Qt Linguist's behaviour, shouldn't `pylupdate4` write paths in the `.ts` file relative to the `.ts` file itself, rather than the `.pro` file
?

### Details

My PyQt project is structured as follows:

```
src/
    my_software.py
    my_software.pro
    my_software/
        module_1.py
        module_2.py
            submodule_1/
                submodule_1_module_1.py
                submodule_1_module_2.py
    resources/
        ui/
            module_1.ui
            module_2.ui
            submodule_1/
                submodule_1_module_1.ui
                submodule_1_module_2.ui
    i18n/
        ts/
            my_software_fr.ts
            my_software_fr.qm
tools/
    tool_1.py
```

The project file (my_software.pro) looks like :

```
FORMS = resources/ui/module_1.ui resources/ui/module_2.ui resources/ui/submodule_1_module_1.ui resources/ui/submodule_1_module_2.ui
SOURCES = my_software/module_1.py my_software/module_2.py resources/ui/submodule_1_module_1.py resources/ui/submodule_1_module_2.py
TRANSLATIONS = i18n/ts/my_software_fr.ts
```

Qt Linguist searches for the files in e.g.

```
/absolute/path/to/project/src/i18n/ts/my_software/module_1.py
```

instead of

```
/absolute/path/to/project/src/my_software/module_1.py
```

The `.ts` (my_software_fr.ts) file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0" language="fr_FR">
<context>
    <name>Class</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="my_software/module_1.py" line="134"/>
        <source>Source text</source>
        <translation>Translated text</translation>
```

Qt Linguist version 4.8.6

`pylupdate4` version 4.8.6

### Edit

In the [source code of PyQt v4.11.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.3/), file metatranslator.cpp, l.470-471, the file path is supposed to be written relative to the .ts file:

```
QDir tsPath = QFileInfo(filename).absoluteDir(); 
QString fn = tsPath.relativeFilePath(msg.fileName()).replace('\\','/');
t << " <location filename=\"" << fn << "\" line=\"" << msg.lineNumber() << "\"/>\n";
```

But [`relativeFilePath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#relativeFilePath) expects an absolute path. When given a relative path, it returns a relative paht. And in my case, `msg.fileName()` is the relative path I entered in the `.pro` file.

I can patch pylupdate to fix this:

```
--- metatranslator.cpp.bak      2015-03-12 10:39:18.984232622 +0100
+++ metatranslator.cpp  2015-03-12 10:37:36.225524474 +0100
@@ -471,8 +471,10 @@
             t << ">\n";
             if (!msg.fileName().isEmpty() && msg.lineNumber() >= 0) {
                 QDir tsPath = QFileInfo(filename).absoluteDir();
-                QString fn = tsPath.relativeFilePath(msg.fileName()).replace('\\','/');
-                t << " <location filename=\"" << fn << "\" line=\"" << msg.lineNumber() << "\"/>\n";
+                QDir curdir = QDir(".");
+                curdir.makeAbsolute();
+                QString fn = tsPath.relativeFilePath(curdir.filePath(msg.fileName())).replace('\\','/');
+                t << "        <location filename=\"" << fn << "\" line=\"" << msg.lineNumber() << "\"/>\n";
             }
             t  << "        <source>" << evilBytes( msg.sourceText(),
                                                   msg.utf8() )
```

Or should the .pro file contain absolute paths ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question *should* be to eliminate the `pro` file and do everything from the command-line (or, even better, via a makefile).

However, there are several crucial options provided with Qt's `lupdate` tool that are not available with `pylupdate` (most importantly, `-locations` and `-codecfortr`).

Without those, it seems the only sane way to do things is to put all the translations files together in one directory, and ensure all the relevant paths are referenced relative to it. To me, that looks like a perfectly acceptable solution, since no other part of a pyqt project should care about the `pro` file (unlike a C++ project).

Comment: I tried command line at first but add issues so I figured the .pro file was the only (reasonably simple) way. I agree that putting the .pro file in the ts/ directory is not a big deal as it is only used for translations anyway. But it is still a workaround and I wanted to know the "recommended" way. AFAIU, the paths have to be absolute in the .pro file or there is a bug in pylupdate (see my Edit with proposed path). I still wonder how the other users  manage this.

Comment: The bug was fixed today. I'm accepting your answer as it is fine as a workaround until next release.